# Increase Baud Rate using a high speed USB Com Port

Tags: c#, port

I need to communicate with a device that has a baud rate of 921.6kBaud.
Now it does come with its own GUI, but i do not want to use this and just want to send a couple of messages to the device via a visual studio piece of software.
Now I have a high speed USB-COM port which i can use with the GUI provided with the device and it all works fine, yet Visual Studio does not allow me to use a baud rate any higher than 256000 within my own software.
How do i achieve this?
Slightly confused to how it can communicate with its own GUI at the baud rate, but this speed can't be achieved using visual studio and the PCs settings?

Comment: "Visual Studio does not allow me" I highly doubt VS allows you to do anything but code. It's .NET what you refer to, not VS

Comment: Yes you are right.... apologies.... .NET does not allow me to increase baud rate. Do you have any actual help with this please?

Comment: .NET is not involved either, it is entirely up to the device driver that emulates the serial port.  The vendor's app probably does not use a serial port but talks to the USB device directly, that is not unusual.  Use a telephone to ask them.

Comment: It is possible in visual studio to connect to your device via a fake serial port. In this manner I was able to send AT commands to a SIM device. It was seen as a modem.